# How to upload media to AWS S3 via CloudFront

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend, amazon-cloudfront

I need to upload files to my S3 bucket using CloudFront. I tried to send GET & PUT requests to cloudfront, and all I get - 403 response.

Get response (with Key Pair ID cookies) gets this

[image]

Put requests get either:

```
<Code>MalformedXML</Code>
<Message>The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema</Message>
```

or:

```
<Code>NotSignedUp</Code>
<Message>Your account is not signed up for the S3 service. You must sign up before you can use S3.</Message>
```

Maybe smthg is wrong with bucket/CF settings.

CloudFront behavior settings:

[image]

Comment: Is this a very new AWS account?

Comment: no, itexists for some time

Comment: Have you specified IAM policies to allow cloudfront to get items from the bucket?